# Why Jacobian matrix is a special case of alternant matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't quite understand why a standard Jacobian matrix
$$JF(x) = \left[{\partial F_i\over \partial x_j}\right]_{ij}$$

is [alternant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternant_matrix).

Because I think Jacobian matrix uses the same $\alpha$, or the same variate in the expression, so it is not a alternant matrix.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Define $$f_i(x)={\partial F_i(x)\over \partial x}$$and try to represent $J\ F(x)$ as a matrix with entries being of form $f_i(x_j)$.